# Auto Delete session files of session-file-store

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

How can I automatically delete expired session files? it still persists even if I restart the server.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "nabeel",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new FileStore({ ttl: 10 }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 10
    }
}))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try to change the `reapInterval` ?

The default value is set to one hour...

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "nabeel",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new FileStore({
       ttl: 10,
       reapInterval: 10
    }),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 10
    }
}))
```

Comment: It worked! , Thanks, but now the problem is that even if there is no session, even expired session files in the directory, its showing deleting expired sessions. Is there a way to only delete the session file if there is an expired session? [session-file-store] Deleting expired sessions @bernad-patrick